# Why do i get Lens reflection in final photo with Lee Nd filter super stopper 15 stops

Tags: filters, neutral-density, light-leaks, lee

Why do i get Lens reflection in final photo with Lee Nd filter super stopper 15 stops   100x100mm
I have attached photos of final picture and the set up i am using a 77mm adpater ring and holder
Lens-tamron 10-24mm
I have also taped up my viewfinder as i have heard this can let light through onto the lens but no difference

[image][image]

Comment: What does the back and sides of the filter setup look like?

Answer (score 2):

As BobT noted, you are getting light leakage from behind the filter.

Lee's "Stopper" line of filters have a foam gasket on the back side of the filter, on all edges. For extreme filters such as the ND4.5 / 15-stop Super Stopper, it's absolutely imperative to block all light leaks.

Looking at your Zomei filter holder, there is no single flat surface where a square foam gasket will completely block all extraneous light from behind:

- The "scallops" at the top left and right will likely cut the corners behind the gasket.
- It looks like it might be possible for light to leak behind the filter at the very top and bottom because the curvature of the filter holder might be larger than the dimension of the filter.
- The adapter ring surface does not sit flush with the front face of the filter holder. If it were to sit flush, as the Lee filter holder does, it would provide additional gasket bearing surface on the tops and sides of the filter, to help block more light.

I believe your Zomei filter holder is not up to par for light stopping filters such as the Little/Big/Super Stoppers. It's probably fine for 1–4 stop ND or ND grad filters, etc. (which don't have light-blocking gaskets), but not for any gasketed filter.

To make up for the light leaking on the Zomei, you will need to be diligent to *completely* block the light from behind with light-blocking material, gaffer's tape, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the information it all makes sense now.I am going to purchase another nd holder that is sealed a lot of money but hopefully this works. Thanks for all the comments on this question much appreciated

Comment: @Ryan I use the Lee filter holder myself. But if you don't think you'll make much use of graduated ND filters in conjunction with the super stopper, you might consider round screw-on ND filters instead, as BobT suggests.

Comment: A lot of time the cheaper third party holders let the light leak in on the *sides* where the holder is punched out to grip the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Since the filter is a slide-in type rather than a screw-in type there is some potential for light leakage around the frame of the filter and/or holder. Normally this may not matter, but with the long exposures you're making -any- leakage can show up. Try putting a dark-cloth or other light opaque material over the camera/filter assembly, making sure to cover the edges of the filter assembly. Opaque black tape might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I got a 100x100mm nb would a 100x150mm filter help this as my cheaper filters were this size and i got no problem with this what so ever?

Comment: @Ryan Do the Stoppers come in 100x150mm? I don't think they do (no need for them to be rectangular, since they don't need to slide up/down like ND grads need to)

Comment: @Ryan No... I don't think that alone would fix the problem. In fact, it'll make it more difficult to mask out extraneous light. IMHO a screw-in filter is the best way to go... I don't know what your 'cheaper' filters do, but I doubt that they require the exposure that the 15 stop ND requires, so leakage is less of an issue.

Comment: It's really not so much about the filter as it is about the holder. Some of the cheaper off-brand holders are bad about letting light through the sides of the holder.

Answer (score 0):

The next problem you will encounter after fixing the filter light leakage will be the camera viewfinder light leakage, if you try using your strong ND filter outdoors (the problem probably won't show up indoors, which is why you haven't seen it yet).  Slip the DK-5 eyepiece cover over the eyepiece.  You can attach the DK-5 onto the camera strap so you'll have it when you need it, and you can leave it on the strap while slipping it over the eyepiece. 
This works better than tape, which can leave undesired residue.  Higher-end Nikons have an eyepiece shutter for the same purpose.